# Building APK removes native library version number from filename

Tags: android, apk, native, version-numbering, android-native-library

I have a legacy code that uses autotools to build shared libraries. These libraries need to be used in an Android application so I've created a simple Java class and JNI wrapper for it (as a shared .so library).

I already have Android.mk script that properly executes legacy build system, builds native library for Java program and links it.

The output files are as follow:

```
libs/armeabi/lib-a.so.0
libs/armeabi/lib-b.so.2
libs/armeabi/lib-wrapper.so
```

`lib-wrapper.so` depends on both libraries `lib-a` and `lib-b`. Notice that the legacy autotools setup adds version number to shared library file name - which is embedded as dependency in `lib-wrapper.so`.

```
# arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -d ./lib-wrapper.so 
Dynamic section at offset 0x7608 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [lib-b.so.2]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [lib-a.so.0]
```

**The problem:**

during APK building the (eg. export unsigned package from Eclipse) the version numbers
are stripped from file names. This results in error:

> Cannot load library: link_image[1721]:
>   30 could not load needed library 'lib-b.so.2' for 'lib-wrapper.so'

because APK contains file `lib-b.so`.

**How can I force retaining version numbers during APK building?**

Modifying legacy build system is rather not possible (until it's a must) as the same setup is used to build x86 libraries/execs.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution without changing the build system?

Comment: Nope. We've added some scripts to manually rename files. But I haven't touched that in 1 year so.. Now with gradle, maybe it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The android linker does not recognise the shared libraries not ending with ".so". You need to change the filename created by the legacy build system.